# how to handle input output data with interrupt

Tags: c++, multithreading, interrupt, rtos, keil

I have started learning multi threading system using RL-ARM RTX with at91sam7 micro-controller.
I have to get input data (as command + data) with interrupt

```
 ______________________________________
| cmd | Data_len |     ...data...      |
----------------------------------------
```

cmd length : **2bytes**
data_len length  : **2 bytes**
data length : **Data_len bytes**

And i should send a response message (with length of 0 - N bytes) to each command with the same USART port.
For now i am getting each input byte, one by one with an interrupt and put the bytes in a buffer.
What is the best way to **handle both input and response message** *without losing any bytes* and also **not killing processor time**, while waiting in the interrupt handler for data transmit?

Comment: Does your microcontroller hava a DMA?

Comment: @MikeMB i use at91sam7x256 as it says [here](http://www.keil.com/dd/chip/4081.htm) it have Thirteen Peripheral DMA Controller Channels. I am not familiar with DMA but as i read [this wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_memory_access) it seems to be the solution. could you give some information or a sample for getting start using DMA

Comment: How complex is it to assemble the response?  Do you have to enter user-state to do that? If so, it's usual to signal a user -state thread to manage the data, especially if message buffering is required because command/response pairs overlap, ie. if a new command can start to come in while the previous command/response is still being processed.

Comment: @MartinJames . Yes i need message buffering. But what should i do in user-state thread? you mean something like assigning a UUID to each command and response? or /and what else? Thank you for your response